# Rerouting to path upon submit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm giving the user the ability to reset their password and then reroute upon completion. However when using form tags and redirect_to, I'm getting some undesired rerouting.

Upon successful submission, the form should reroute to:

https://myherokuapp.herokuapp.com/customer_password_resets/new

but instead it reroute to:

https://myherokuapp/customer_password_resets/create.ShoyTPeAC5UAEjjWwZh_HA       //the extra piece is the token id

**CustomerPasswordResetsController Controller**

```
def edit
 @customer = Customer.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end

def update
 @customer = Customer.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
 if @customer.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  redirect_to new_customer_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
elsif @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
  redirect_to new_customer_password_reset_path, :notice => "Password has been reset!"
else
  render :edit
 end
end
```

**customer_password_resets/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @customer, :url => customer_password_resets_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @customer.errors.full_messages %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password" %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The url option is the problem there. Rails will submit alright. The new view will submit to a create action and the edit to the update

Comment: So do I need to create a new view or change the submit form ?

Comment: Only change the form. Remove the url option from the form helper

Comment: Removing the url reroutes to customer/id, not customer_resets_new

Comment: Maybe I was wrong!! Use the url option as before but add the method: :put/:patch option. You have `resource :customer_password_resets` in routes.rb right ?

Comment: Yes. I just needed to remove the params and define the method as a post

Comment: Nice. Anyway remember that post method matches with create actions and put methods with update actions, keeping things RESTful

Answer (score 0):

Update, the previous answer did sucesfully reroute but did not update. I need the params in order to find the user in the update model. Rake routes showed that I indeed needed to change this from post to patch !

```
<%= form_for @customer, :url => customer_password_resets_path, :method => :patch do |f| %>
```